# Force SBT to follow redirects for an explicit github releases URL

Tags: scala, github, dependencies, sbt

The new [github releases feature](https://github.com/blog/1547-release-your-software) makes it possible post .jars for people who don't want or need to build them. Poking at it a little with wget reveals that github is using a redirect under the hood to an S3 bucket to support this capability. If I do the following in my build.sbt file:

```
libraryDependencies += "edu.chop.cbmi" % "DataExpress" % "0.9.1.3" from "http://github.com/cbmi/dataexpress/releases/download/0.9.1.3/dataexpress_2.10-0.9.1.3.jar"
```

I get the following error from SBT:

```
[info] downloading http://github.com/cbmi/dataexpress/releases/download/0.9.1.3/dataexpress_2.10-0.9.1.3.jar ...
[warn]  [FAILED     ] edu.chop.cbmi#DataExpress;0.9.1.3!DataExpress.jar: The HTTP response code for http://github.com/cbmi/dataexpress/releases/download/0.9.1.3/dataexpress_2.10-0.9.1.3.jar did not indicate a success. See log for more detail. (303ms)
```

I presume SBT is not following the redirect, but I can't see anywhere as to how to set this. Is there a way to force SBT to follow redirects?

Comment: It seems it isn't SBT itself but Ivy that doesn't follow redirects, so I don't think there is an option somewhere to change it, sadly. The error comes from [ivy's wrapper over Apache HttpClient](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/ant/ivy/core/tags/2.3.0/src/java/org/apache/ivy/util/url/HttpClientHandler.java) (line 115)